# How to pass an observer from the observer?

Tags: event-observer

```
public function someObserver($observer) {

    Mage::dispatchEvent('some_event', ?);

}
```

What do we need to have instead of a `?`? $observer? But it expects array. I want the observer that catches `some_event` to have the same values as `someObserver` does.

Comment: Have you tried passing array('observer'=>$observer) there?

Comment: yes, but then you need to do getObserver(), not sure if that's good @DmitryR

Comment: I think it's usual way of getting data from Magento's object instance - via getters. Not sure if that's bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public function someObserver($observer)
{
    Mage::dispatchEvent('some_event', $observer->getEvent()->getData());
}
```